# Sharepoint Document Library get file count using REST API

Tags: c#, rest, sharepoint, sharepointdocumentlibrary

I use Sharepoint Document Library for storing different documents.
Any user can add multiple files and folders in this Document Library.

My requirement is to get the total count of files inside root folder (including sub-folders) using SharePoint REST API call.

Currently I am iterating through all folders and getting file count in loop which gives very bad performance when folders are recursive and huge in number.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

[https://bamgroup.sharepoint.com/sites/[siteID]/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeURL('Shared%20Documents')](https://bamgroup.sharepoint.com/sites/%5BsiteID%5D/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeURL(%27Shared%20Documents%27))

This returns the following output:

```
{
    odata.metadata: https://bamgroup.sharepoint.com/sites/032204/_api/$metadata#SP.ApiData.Folders1/@Element,
    odata.type: SP.Folder,
    odata.id: https://bamgroup.sharepoint.com/sites/032204/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='/sites/032204/Project Files'),
    odata.editLink: Web/GetFolderByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='/sites/032204/Project%20Files'),
    Exists: true,
    IsWOPIEnabled: false,
    ItemCount: 3,
    Name: Project Files,
    ProgID: null,
    ServerRelativeUrl: /sites/123456/Shared Documents,
    TimeCreated: 2021-11-25T10:54:23.000000+00:00,
    TimeLastModified: 2021-12-13T10:44:14.000000+00:00,
    UniqueId: 60bd12e0-978c-417d-919d-2be26fe2fecb,
    WelcomePage: 
}
```